# Read that many rows into the recordset, as there are used cells in column B in Excel file, using ADODB connection with EXCEL;

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, ado

Most important thing is that the code is written in Word VBA Editor and it's lunched from Word .docm file.

From this Word .docm  file I'm connecting into the Excel file (using ADODB connection), which serves as a client database, and I'm reading whole sheet from that file (sheet name = "data") into a dynamic array which will be searched later.

The problem is that in this Excel file, there is an index number in column A, that's manually pre-populated, using fill with series, up to row 70000 . And at the same time, the real data, that starts from column B has only 182 rows filled.

So the question is: **How to retrieve only the amount of rows, that's effectively filled** (last used row in column B) into the record set, that's pulled from this file - of course without opening the file. And using ADODB connection with EXCEL.

I ask this question because later in the code, I need the number of rows in the record set to write it into a dynamic array (using ReDim statement), which I'll need later to search and to populate the word file automatically.

Here is the code I got so far: (macro will be lunched from Word file)

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UseADOSelect()

Dim connection As New ADODB.connection
Dim recSet As New ADODB.Recordset    'All the results of the query are placed in a record set;
Dim exclApp As Excel.Application
Dim exclWorkbk As Excel.Workbook
Dim mySheet As Excel.Worksheet
Dim wordDoc As Word.Document
Dim cntCntrl As ContentControl
Dim strPESELfromWord As String
Dim strQuery As String
Dim intWiersz As Integer
Dim intRemainder As Integer
Dim intRow As Integer
Dim arraySize As Integer
Dim strSexDigit As String
Dim strArray() As String
Dim i As Integer

Set wordDoc = Word.ActiveDocument
Debug.Print wordDoc

strPESELfromWord = Trim(Selection.Text)
Debug.Print strPESELfromWord
Word.Application.Visible = True

strSexDigit = Mid(strPESELfromWord, 10, 1)      'Extract 10th digit from PESEL number
Debug.Print strSexDigit
intRemainder = strSexDigit Mod 2
Debug.Print intRemainder

connection.Open "Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = X:\Roesler\Excel\FW 1\custdb.xlsm;" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"                 'now it works
                                                             

strQuery = "SELECT * From [data$]"     '[data$]   is the table name; in this case it's the sheet name;
'recSet.Open strQuery, connection
recSet.Open strQuery, connection, adOpenStatic        ' Or specify adOpenStatic in the Open method directly.
Debug.Print " RecordCount = " & recSet.RecordCount             'https://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html
Debug.Print recSet.EOF      'Returns a value that indicates whether the current record position is after the last record in a Recordset object.
                            'At the moment the value is "False".
                            
                            
Debug.Print " RecordCount = " & recSet.RecordCount             'https://www.geeksengine.com/article/recordcount-ado-recordset-vba.html


arraySize = recSet.RecordCount   'I wanted to assign total number of records to arraySize variable to use it later in ReDim statement.
Debug.Print arraySize

ReDim strArray(1 To arraySize)
For i = 1 To arraySize
   strArray(i) = recSet(i)
Next i

intRow = 2

'  For Each cntCntrl In ActiveDocument.ContentControls
'    If cntCntrl.Title = "02KlientPelneImie" Then cntCntrl.Range.Text = objExcel.Sheets("data").Cells(intWiersz, 4)
'    If cntCntrl.Title = "02KlientNrDowodu" Then cntCntrl.Range.Text = objExcel.Sheets("data").Cells(intWiersz, 9)
'  Next
```

Suppose there is 182 effectively filled rows in my Excel file (Worksheets("data")) - there is no blank cells either in column B or C until the first empty cell in column B or C, that's going to be "B183" and "C183" at the moment, but the first empty cell in these columns changes, as new customer data populates subsequent rows.

But there never gonna be a situation, where there are blank cells inside columns B and C other than first empty cell in those columns.

Comment: @slightly snarky  Added clarification regarding your question, in the end of the post (my question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your connection string says that your columns have names in the top row of cells.

Suppose column B is called "mycolumn"

Then you need to change

```
strQuery = "SELECT * From [data$]"
```

to

```
strQuery = "SELECT * From [data$] WHERE mycolumn <> ''"
```

or you might need

```
strQuery = "SELECT * From [data$] WHERE mycolumn <> '' AND mycolumn IS NOT NULL"
```

Comment: ```strQuery = "SELECT * From [data$] WHERE mycolumn <> ''"``` this statement did the job - Thanks.